# Create terrazzo material/pattern with the standard textures

Tags: texturing, materials

is it possible to create this kind of material with the standard textures? The Voronoi texture (set to cells) is coming close but I don’t know if it is possible to a) set the single cells apart from each other and b) to give them seperate colors.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303262/procedural-recycled-plastic-material/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250538/how-to-create-this-white-chocolate-with-cookies-realistically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just switch a Voronoi texture to *Cells* coloring, and drive it through a *Color Ramp* node set to *Constant* interpolation mode.

Adjust the *Color Ramp* stops to the desired color ratio so that the amount of colored flakes is close to the reference image.

You would generally want narrow black, orange and green strips, over a broader white background, so adjust proportions accordingly.

Speckle size can be adjusted from texture scale parameter. Changing size may also require adjusting color stop positions.

[image]