# How can I get this recycled plastic material with a procedural shader?

Tags: shaders, procedural

How can I get this recycled plastic material with a procedural shader? [image]

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot simply use a given image as a texture?  Is there some constraints that can be added to you question?

Comment: I understand, I can make it with texture. But want to make it by procedural texture for better control on the pattern.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132854/create-terrazzo-material-pattern-with-the-standard-textures https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303262/procedural-recycled-plastic-material/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250538/how-to-create-this-white-chocolate-with-cookies-realistically