# Procedural Recycled Plastic Material

Tags: texturing, procedural

I'm not new to blender but still not really there yet in regards of procedural materials.

I'm looking to recreate a recycled plastic material [image] [image]

there's already [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204977/how-can-i-get-this-recycled-plastic-material-with-a-procedural-shader) thread

which in turn links to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132854/create-terrazzo-material-pattern-with-the-standard-textures) thread recommending using voronoi texture

which is only doing half of the job.

I'm sure there is a way to set up a shader that can achieve flexibility in regards of patterns, colors, direction of the speckles and subsurface scattering. Additionally there's also real life examples of pieces of plastic with tool marks on the surface
[image],
I think that's straight forward using whatever displacement texture.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250538/how-to-create-this-white-chocolate-with-cookies-realistically

Comment: This is great although probably a little bit inflexible since it's not a material but a particle system. But will definitely give it a try! It looks great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by no means perfect and just thought as an idea to start from: I've made a material that is basically transparent, with added translucency for that not-completely-opaque plastic look. Then also volume for the inner parts shining through.  Everything colored with a slightly distorted Voronoi texture. And to make this all work the bounces for *Volume* under *Light Paths* are increased to 3 instead of the default 0. The result looks like this:

[image: translucent plastic]

And this is the material setup:

[image: shader nodetree]

Comment: This does look promising! I will try a couple of things with your setup, Gordon, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please take your time to read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This might not be the perfect answer, but your reference materials looked quite different and it would be too elaborate to try and recreate everything here.