translucent white resin with embeddings - material
I need to make a volumetric translucent material, possibly working in EEVEE.
It is a white semi-translucent resin with objects embedded.
The embedded objects are more visible near to the surface of the resin, as you can see in the reference image.
now, the transmission parameter in eevee does a pretty good work at gradually blurring the objects behind (or inside) a transmissive surface.
what i'd need is that the more the rear object blurs, the more it goes less visible, taking the base color of the transmissive surface.
Any ideas?
Thanks



Hello, you could also plug a Principled Volume into the Volume input of the Output, but in Eevee it won't be as good as in Cycles

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303262/procedural-recycled-plastic-material/303266#303266
